# bash: string value based entries filtering

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, conditional-statements

I have this check in my script:

```
[[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="$VALUE"
```

It is writing lines that contain contact* from one file to an array. How can I add another check that will skip the xi* values in that line and write it in the array?

I tried something like:

```
[[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && [[ $VALUE != "xi*" ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="$VALUE"
```

But it is not working for me. :/

Comment: Take the wildcard outside the quotes: "xi"*

Comment: ...and as a stylistic note rather than a correctness one -- POSIX indicates that all-caps names should be used for variables meaningful to the shell and OS-provided utilities; names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use, and are what you should use in your own code. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: Note also that whether you enabled the `extglob` option impacts (substantially) whether your code here will work. It would be helpful to provide a full [mcve] -- something that (1) sets your `KEY`, (2) sets your `VALUE`, (3) runs any expected prerequisites (like toggling the `extglob` flag; (4) generates output that reflects whether the intended state is set; and (5) provides your expected and actual values of that output in light of 1-4.

Comment: The script is working, extglob is enabled. I just need to add this check to it :) @Charles Duffy - I can paste the whole script in the answer below so you can check it :)

Comment: Bash4 does not require enabling extglob to use them in `[[ .. ]]`.

Comment: @GavinPortwood - it´s not working with your suggestion. :/

Comment: "`xi*` values" are values starting with "xi"? If so, do not compare for equality, you can perform a pattern match (`=~`): `[[ "$VALUE" =~ ^xi.* ]]`. Also no need to chain two separate tests, just place your and inside one pair of `[[`, `]]`.

Comment: @OndrejK. - it´s not working with this try:    `[[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && [[ "$VALUE" =~ ^xi.*]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="$VALUE"`

Comment: Yeah, looking at your examples below. This is probably not what you intend and mean by doesn't work. So, you actually want to dive into a `VALUE` of certain `KEYS` and leave few pieces out of it (the last `,xi...`). Does that sound correct? If so, the next question would be, how stable is the formatting? Would be be enough to just chop off all `,xi...` line ends? Or could this piece appear anywhere else and the `VALUE` would need to be dissected entry by entry?

Comment: I'm not interested in checking your whole script. I'd be happy to check a [mcve], but part of that definition is **minimal** -- the *shortest possible code* that recreates a problem. Otherwise, I'd need to trace through your script to recreate the variables' values at the point you're interested in, and -- nope, not interested. (Also, if I *were* to comment on the whole script, I'd find myself obliged to get pedantic -- there are lots of subtle bugs in there due to bad quoting, use of `${foo[*]}` instead of `"${foo[@]}"`, and the like -- but with a MCVE, those issues are out-of-scope).

Comment: ...so, give us something like `KEY=contacts; VALUE=xivar; if [[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && [[ "$VALUE" =~ ^xi.* ]]; then echo "Desired behavior"; else echo "Undesired behavior"; fi` -- short, simple, self-contained, to-the-point, and clearly distinguishing between the behavior you want and the behavior you actually have.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - the xi* values can appear anywhere in the line that contain contact*

Comment: Again: provide a specific example of the `KEY` and `VALUE` variable contents for which the one line you say is your problem doesn't do what you want, akin to my [example above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373307/bash-string-value-based-entries-filtering?noredirect=1#comment85751335_49373307). Otherwise we need to analyze your program to figure out how a "line" corresponds to the values -- you should be doing that debugging yourself as part of building a [mcve].

Comment: ...in this case Armali did it for you, but if you'd put in a line like `declare -p KEY VALUE >&2` line to log your values when the failure took place (so you could tell us that unexpected behavior was happening with `VALUE=foo,ximersic` instead of `VALUE=ximersic`), you would have been able to ask a much more focused question and get an answer much more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first file looks like this:
>
> ```
> …
>     contacts                        Marko Geršić,Mijo,nagiosadmin,Patrick,ximgersic
> …
> ```
>
> The second file needs to look like this:
>
> ```
> …
>     contacts                        Marko Geršić,Mijo,nagiosadmin,Patrick
> …
> ```
>
> So, without the xi* in the contact* lines.

Since the `xi*` is at the end of the `$VALUE`, you can simply use the [**`bash` Parameter Expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) *Remove matching suffix pattern*:

```
  [[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="${VALUE%,xi*}"
```

> xi* values aren´t always at the end of the line

If the `xi*` is amid the `$VALUE` elements, you could use *Pattern substitution*:

```
  [[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="${VALUE/,xi*([^,])}"
```

> and if there are multiple xi* values?

To delete multiple `xi*` elements, you just have to double the `/` above:

```
  [[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="${VALUE//,xi*([^,])}"
```

Comment: xi* values aren´t always at the end of the line :/

Comment: Then go with the latter recommendation (fixing the regex along the way) and be aware this really only works well if there is only one match for a value starting with `xi`. If there can be multiple entries, manipulating `VALUE` is not enough. Break it into individual entries, filter, reassemble.

Comment: @Armali - and if there are multiple xi* values? Tnx for this solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

`[[ $KEY == contact@(s|_groups) ]] && CONFIG[$KEY]="${VALUE//xi*([^,])}" && CONFIG[$KEY]="${VALUE//,xi*([^,])}"`

This is the check that gave me the wanted results. :)